# Automatically pick scale error, how to solve?

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8

I am new in R. I found an error when trying to plot monthly anomaly temperature as the following;

```
> country.list <- c("ISL", "FIN", "NOR", "SWE")
> country.dat <- get_ensemble_stats(country.list, "manom", "tmin_means")
No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
> country.dat.b1 <- subset(country.dat, country.dat$scenario == "b1")
> ountry.dat.b1 <- subset(country.dat.b1, country.dat.b1$percentile == 50)
> country.dat.b1 <- subset(country.dat.b1, country.dat.b1$fromYear == 2081)
> ggplot(country.dat.b1, aes(x = month, y = data, group = locator, colour = locator)) +
+     geom_point() + geom_path() + ylab("Average daily minimum temperature") +
+     theme_bw() + xlab("Month")
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type list. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'month' not found
```

However, it worked fine for monthly average "mavg". How to fix it?

Thank you very much

Comment: Where does `get_ensemble_stats()` come from? What does it return?

Comment: Found [get_ensemble_stats](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rWBclimate/rWBclimate.pdf) in the rWBclimate package.

Comment: Yes get_ensemble_stats come from rWBclimate  package. Normally, plot is work for "mavg", but it returned error for "manom".